# Help in a step in the proof of Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following.

Let $f$ be a nonnegative locally integrable function for the Borel regular measure $\mu$, if for al $x\in A \subset X$ we have
$$\limsup_{r \to 0 } \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} f d\mu \geq t$$
for some $t>0$, then
$$\int_A f d\mu \geq t\mu(A)  $$

Context: We are working in a doubling metric measure space (X,\mu) so that Vitali covering theorem holds, this problem is a step in the proof of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem of the book Lectures on analysis on metric spaces by Heinonen, theorem 1.8. The author does not prove this step so i'm trying to do it myself.

So this is what I tried, let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $C \subset A$ be a closed set such that $\mu(A) - \epsilon < \mu(C)$, also notice that we can find closed balls of arbitrarily small radii such that they cover $A$ and
$$\frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))} \geq t-\epsilon $$
indeed, fix $\delta > 0$ small, then there is $r' < \delta$ such that
$$\frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r'))} \int_{B(x,r')} f d\mu \geq sup_{: r \in(0,\delta)} \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} f d\mu  \geq-\epsilon \leq sup_{ r \in (0,\delta') }\frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} f d\mu-\epsilon$$
where $\delta' < \delta$ then letting $\delta' \to 0$ we obtain
$$\frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r'))} \int_{B(x,r')} f d\mu \geq \limsup_{r \to 0 } \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} f d\mu  - \epsilon \geq t-\epsilon  $$

since $\delta$ was arbitrarily small, we get what we claimed.

Therefore this collection of balls cover $A$ and their radii is arbitrarily small for each $x \in A$ so that they satisfy Vitali covering theorem, therefore we can find a subcollection of countable disjoint balls that cover $A$ a.e, so that
$$\int_A f d\mu \geq \sum_i \int_{U \cap B_i} f d\mu $$
this is the step where I am stuck, I don't know how to manipulate those integrals so that I integrate over the ball and can use the previous inequality, any help would be appreciated.